# Why does Path.GetFileName() return the name of the correct folder, but Path.GetDirectoryName() returns it parent folder?

Tags: c#, winforms, path, treeview, directory

I have found that using `Path.GetFileName()` in the code below works as I intend and gives me the name of the correct folder, but if I use `Path.GetDirectoryName()` it returns the name of the parent (UserGeneratedContent) folder instead. Why does this occur when both methods are passed the same path as a string? And why does `Path.GetFileName()` work on directories?

When I use `Path.GetFileName()` the text of the nodes in the Treeview are those of the folders it finds - this is what I want to happen, but if I use `Path.GetDirectoryName()` the text is the full path from *@"UserGeneratedContent"* on down for each node. Why does that happen?

And lastly, can my code be improved?

```
private void CheckForBaseFolder()
{
    if (Directory.Exists(@"UserGeneratedContent"))
    {
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(@"UserGeneratedContent");
        DirectoryInfo[] subdirs = info.GetDirectories();

        if (subdirs.Length != 0)
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(@"UserGeneratedContent", subdirs[0].ToString());
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(CheckForSubFolders(path));
            treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];
        }
        else { MessageBox.Show("No User-Generated Folders Or Files Found"); }    
    }
    else { Directory.CreateDirectory(@"UserGeneratedContent"); }
}

private TreeNode CheckForSubFolders(string path)
{
    TreeNode folder = new TreeNode(path);

    folder.Text = Path.GetFileName(path); // Works as intended, but.....
    folder.Text = Path.GetDirectoryName(path); // Returns the parent folder 

    foreach(var subdirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        folder.Nodes.Add(CheckForSubFolders(subdirectory));                
    }

    folder.ImageIndex = 0;
    folder.SelectedImageIndex = 1;

    return folder;
}
```

Comment: Possible typo? They both call the same function..

Comment: @ Simon Whithead - yes a typo, fixed it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Are you able to pop an example value of `path` in there somewhere?

Comment: Path names are ambiguous.  Take a path name like `c:\foo\bar`.  Is that a *directory* name bar?  Or is that a *file* named bar in the foo directory?  The only way to find out is to hit the disk and check.  The Path class refuses to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your code, you are passing the path that doesn't contain filename but the last part of the path is directory UserGeneratedContent. `Path.GetFileName` returns the ["The characters after the last directory character in path"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) so it retuns the last directory name instead of filename (you can make a file without extension). When you call  `Path.GetDirectoryName()` on the same path string it returns ["Directory information for path"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx).

Check this code to see what I'm referring to:

Suppose you have directory "one" on C partition, and directory "two" in directory "one", and a file named "three.txt" in directory "two", when you execute this code it will produce:

```
string directory = Path.GetFileName(@"C:\one\two");
directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\one\two");
```

`directory` will hold first "two" and then "C:\one"

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(@"C:\one\two\three.txt");
directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\one\two\three.txt");
```

but now, `filename` will hold "three.txt" and `directory` will hold "C:\one\two"

**EDIT:***This is later edit after the comments*. I would modify the `CheckForSubFolders` method this way:

```
private TreeNode CheckForSubFolders(string path)
    {

        TreeNode folder = new TreeNode(path);
        string dir = path.TrimEnd(new char[] { '\\' });
        int index = dir.LastIndexOf('\\');
        folder.Text = dir.Substring(index + 1);

        //But I think that it is OK to use folder.Text = Path.GetFileName(path); 
        //since the filename of some file will never be passed to the CheckForSubFolders method         

        foreach(var subdirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {

            folder.Nodes.Add(CheckForSubFolders(subdirectory));
        }

        folder.ImageIndex = 0;
        folder.SelectedImageIndex = 1;
        return folder;
    }
```

Comment: @Nick, thank you for a clear and concise answer. I understand now what is happening. Path.GetFileName() gets the job done, but I'd rather use Path.GetDirectoryName() as it is a folder I'm searching for. I'm unsure exactly how to modify my code to use the latter method. I cannot hardcode the path as I want to let the user create a folder with a name of their own choosing. How would you do it? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You could use this code if you want:
string dir = "C:\\A\\B\\D";
dir = dir.TrimEnd(new char[] { '\\' });
int index = dir.LastIndexOf('\\');
dir = dir.Substring(index + 1);

Comment: Nick, I am a bit confused. For starters I don't know the absolute path to 'UserGeneratedContent' from the root of the drive. I am working on a portable, standalone, single *.exe application which could be located anywhere on a hard disk or usb flash drive. Currently the path to the folder I want is ......\UserGeneratedContent\This is the folder I want as my Root node\Next folder\etc.

Comment: @TheThing So you want to find full path to the UserGeneratedContent folder not knowing where it is?Am I getting you right?

Comment: @TheThing Is that folder next to your program .exe file or can be anywhere on the disk?

Comment: @TheThing Check the answer edit, I think this is your answer.

Comment: @Nick, The folder 'UserGeneratedContent' resides in the same folder as my *.exe (which can be located anywhere - on a HD or USB flash drive) It is created at runtime if it does not already exist. I want my application to allow the user to create a sub-folder within 'UserGeneratedContent' with any valid name of their own choosing. This sub-folder - lets call it 'I Love C#' will be the root node in my treeview and all nodes added thereafter will correspond to sub-folders created within 'I Love C#'

Answer (score 2):

Simply becasue as MSDN cliams for [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx):

> In most cases, the string returned by this method consists of all
>   characters in the path up to but not including the last
>   DirectorySeparatorChar or AltDirectorySeparatorChar.

So if the parameter, is the path to directory itself, it just picks its parent directory, if any.

Answer (score 1):

First of all how can you tell a difference from path that points to file from that which is pointing to a direcotry? Simply you cannot because you can create a file named `file` (does not contain a dot `.` and any extension) and you can create a folder that contains a dot `folder.txt`.

So how would you implement the logic that determines if path points to a file?

To answer your question methods `GetFileName` and `GetDirectoryName` simply assume that the last path part is a file name.

Comment: This is a good point. Surely there must be another (and likely much easier) way to determine whether a path points to a folder or directory (maybe contentType?) At the very least, I suppose you could pull some method that's supposed to only work with files and not directories and catch the null reference exception, maybe?

Comment: You of course assumes that given path exists and if not? was that file missing or directory missing :). Those two methods in question don't care if path exists they wont check it and they shouldn't. So all we have is a string that the caller says is a path to something so the assumption.